# Resizing div before parent

Tags: html, css

When I resize the page the searchbox starts resizing after the padding of the parent if zero. I want to resize the div with class-"searchbox", with resizing the page not after the parent's padding is off. Here is the code I'll be glad if you correct me anywhere.

```css
.site-wrapper {
  max-width: 86.5rem;
  min-height: 28rem;
  padding: 0 4.3rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  padding-top: 2.7rem;
}

#hamburger-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hamburger-button:hover {
  background-color: #0000001f;
}

#hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url(/assets/menuicon.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  padding: 9.2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-content {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-content-logo {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.3rem;
}

.header-content-logo svg {
  width: 12.6rem;
}

.searchbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 38.7rem;
  height: 2.7rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.searchbox:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 20px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.searchbox input {
  width: 92%;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 11.8pt;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.searchbox input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div id="hamburger-button">
      <button id="hamburger"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
    <div class="header-content-logo">
      <svg>
            </div>
            <div class="searchbox">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search without being tracked">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried putting margin and even making another div before it and putting padding but seems that it didn't make it work. I am out of options.

Comment: Very unclear, perhaps not well explained.